# VS: How to configure DebugWithReleaseCRT?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I added a new configuration `DebugWithReleaseCRT` to our CMake scripts, which is based on pretty standard `Debug` config but links with Release CRT (`/MD` instead of `/MDd`) and defines `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0`. I checked generated project file settings and all looks good:

> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> RuntimeLibrary = Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)

However when I build it I get errors like:

> 3>3rd-party.lib(3rd-party.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected
>   for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value
>   'MDd_DynamicDebug' in My.obj

which I read as:

> your `My.cpp` file is compiled with debug CRT
>   (`MDd_DynamicDebug`) while you're trying to link with library
>   `3rd-party.lib` that is built with release CRT (`MD_DynamicRelease`)

I also checked this particular file (`My.cpp`) settings but nothing fancy there, it inherited `/MD` flag from the parent project.

Why my project is linked with Debug CRT despite of specified `/MD` flag?

Comment: Try cleaning the cache, the object files an rebuild again. Also note that 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug'  message is telling that you are invoking or using a wrong [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html)

Comment: @Joel: it's not cache problem or rebuild, and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is not relevant in VS case

Comment: Is it possible both /MD and /MDd are used on the command line? (Check the "Command Line" in the project settings). Maybe /MDd is overriding /MD, and the IDE isn't displaying it correctly in the project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related with VS precompiler definition [_DEBUG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b98s6w8.aspx)

> The compiler defines _DEBUG when you specify the /MTd or /MDd option.
>   These options specify debug versions of the C run-time library.

As my `DebugWithReleaseCRT` config was based on `Debug`, it copied `_DEBUG` definition too. Turns out that if `_DEBUG` is defined it overrules `/MD` flag (`MD_DynamicRelease`) and VS still links with debug CRT (hey Visual Studio team, that was a surprise!).

The problem was solved by removing `_DEBUG` from `DebugWithReleaseCRT`. Actually it was solved by replacing `_DEBUG` by `NDEBUG` because some 3rd-party dependencies required exactly one of them to be defined. I'm still not sure it's a clean way to configure `DebugWithReleaseCRT`, I don't feel particularly confident about defining `NDEBUG` in kind of debug config.